# Llenar un Input automáticamente dependiendo del valor de otro input

Tags: javascript, asp

Como están amigos, tengo un problema al intentar cargar un texto en un input. Quiero que cuando cargue el valor del input indMasaCorp en situacionIMC debe aparecer "Peso bajo" o "Peso Normal". El valor de indMasaCorp se llena automaticamente al colocar la talla y el peso con la funcion calcularIMC eso si lo puede realizar, pero no me carga el de situacionIMC, el codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```js
 function calcularIMC() {            
            var talla = document.getElementById("txttalla").value;
            var peso = document.getElementById("txtpeso").value;
            var result = peso / (talla * talla);
            if (result == NaN || result == Infinity) {
                document.getElementById("txtimc").value = "";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("txtimc").value = result.toFixed(5);
            }            
        }

        
        function tablaIMC() {
            var imc = document.getElementById("txtimc");
            var situacion = document.getElementById("txtsituacionIMC");                        
            if (imc.value < 18.5) {
                situacion.innerHTML = "Peso Bajo";
            } else {
                situacion.innerHTML = "Peso Normal";
            }
            
        }
```

```html
<div class="form-row mt-4">
        <div class="col-1 pl-1 mr-4">
            <label asp-for="peso" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="peso" class="form-control" id="txtpeso" oninput="calcularIMC()" />
            <span asp-validation-for="peso" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 pl-1 mr-4">
            <label asp-for="talla" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="talla" class="form-control" id="txttalla" oninput="calcularIMC()" />
            <span asp-validation-for="talla" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 pl-1 mr-4">
            <label asp-for="indMasaCorp" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="indMasaCorp" class="form-control"  id="txtimc" oninput="tablaIMC()" disabled/>
            <span asp-validation-for="indMasaCorp" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 pl-1">
            <label asp-for="situacionIMC" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="situacionIMC" class="form-control" id="txtsituacionIMC" disabled/>
            <span asp-validation-for="situacionIMC" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

le hice algunos cambios al codigo. Basicamente debes llamar a tablaIMC() dentro de calcularIMC() y tenias un error al colocar el valor del input, lo hiciste con innerHTML y es con value. Luego si lo quieres colocar en un div, span, etc si puedes usar innerHTML

```
<script>
    function calcularIMC() {            
        var talla = document.getElementById("txttalla").value;
        var peso = document.getElementById("txtpeso").value;
        var result = peso / (talla * talla);
        if (result == NaN || result == Infinity) {
            document.getElementById("txtimc").value = "";
            tablaIMC();
        } else {
            document.getElementById("txtimc").value = result.toFixed(5);
            tablaIMC();
        }            
    }

    
    function tablaIMC() {
        var imc = document.getElementById("txtimc");
        var situacion = document.getElementById("txtsituacionIMC");  
        if(imc.value)
        {                      
            if (imc.value < 18.5) {
                situacion.value = "Peso Bajo";
            } else {
                situacion.value = "Peso Normal";
            }
        }else{
            situacion.value = "";
        }
        
    }
    </script>


    <div class="form-row mt-4">
    <div class="col-1 pl-1 mr-4">
        <label asp-for="peso" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="peso" class="form-control" id="txtpeso" oninput="calcularIMC()" />
        <span asp-validation-for="peso" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 pl-1 mr-4">
        <label asp-for="talla" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="talla" class="form-control" id="txttalla" oninput="calcularIMC()" />
        <span asp-validation-for="talla" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 pl-1 mr-4">
        <label asp-for="indMasaCorp" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="indMasaCorp" class="form-control"  id="txtimc" onchange="tablaIMC()" disabled/>
        <span asp-validation-for="indMasaCorp" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 pl-1">
        <label asp-for="situacionIMC" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="situacionIMC" class="form-control" id="txtsituacionIMC" disabled/>
        <span asp-validation-for="situacionIMC" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente funciono a la perfección; muchas gracias

Comment: ok, márcala como solucionada, saludos